# MySQL connection parameter to ignore tablename

Tags: mysql, connection-string

Is it possible to set a property or variable on MYSQL connect string so that the tablenames are *not* case sensitive when queries are run on the session? MySQL client/server is running on Linux and storage engine is `InnoDB` but can be controlled by specifying `sessionVariables=storage_engine=MyISAM` in the connect string.

```
jdbc:mysql://host:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=storage_engine=MyISAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible via connect string parameters.